# Generic saturation of inner models

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals, inner-models

Say that an inner model $M$ of $V$ is *generically saturated* if for every forcing notion $\Bbb P\in M$, either there is an $M$-generic for $\Bbb P$ in $V$, or forcing with $\Bbb P$ over $V$ collapses cardinals.

> What is the consistency strength of "$L$ is generically saturated"?

If the answer is $0^\#$ exists, is this sort of a general answer for relative constructibility (i.e. $L[A]$ is generically saturated if and only if $A^\#$ exists)? If the answer is negative, what can we conclude from this principle?

Note, [Mohammad Golshani remarks](https://mathoverflow.net/q/207264/7206) (also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/184495/7206)), that assuming $0^\#$ exists for every $\kappa$, $\operatorname{Add}(\kappa,1)^L$ collapses $\kappa$ to $\omega$ (in particular, if $\kappa$ is countable in $V$, it is just a Cohen forcing).

So in the presence of $0^\#$ at least we know that a lot of the forcings in $L$ do collapse cardinals, even if they do not admit generics in $V$ (e.g., $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\omega_1^V)$ cannot admit a generic, although it *does* collapse cardinals).

---

(The idea here is to marry Foreman's maximality principle that states that every forcing adds a real or collapses cardinals, with inner model hypothesis-like ideas.)

Comment: In light of Mohammad's answer, what about the principle, "Whatever statement can be forced is true in an inner model?"  Or more specifically, if $\sigma$ is a sentence and  there is $\mathbb P$ such that $\Vdash^L_{\mathbb P} \sigma$, then there is $\mathbb Q$ and an $L$-generic $G \subseteq \mathbb Q$ in $V$ such that $L[G] \models \sigma$.

Comment: Monroe, the first one is just Sy's IMH, if my memory serves me right. The point is that I don't want just to say that, I want to say that the universe is sort of saturated over the inner model in the sense that anything that doesn't break cardinality (and power sets, it seems) was already done.

Comment: What about replacing powerset with “every set is countable”?

Comment: What ever do you mean by that, Dr. Eskew?

Comment: “Burn them all!”

Comment: So you mean working in 2nd order arithmetic kind of thing?

Comment: Yes, but that sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: You could force with $Col(\omega,<Ord)$ over $L$.

Comment: Yes. I know that. Again, this defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The concept is inconsistent.

Consider $\mathbb{P}=Add(\omega, \kappa)_L=Add(\omega, \kappa),$ where $\kappa$ is $(2^{\aleph_0})^+$ of $V$. Forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ over $V$ doesn't collapse cardinals (it is ccc.c. in $V$) and there is no $M$-generic filter for $\mathbb{P}$ in $V$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Do you think there is an interesting variant there?

Comment: @Yair: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have no idea

Comment: I imagine something like "preserving the continuum function" maybe?

Comment: I just may say the exact version of Stanley's theorem. Suppose $0^\sharp$ exists. if $\mathbb{P} \in L$ is non-trivial and uniform and if $\kappa$ is the least cardinal such that forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ over $L$ adds a fresh subset of $\kappa$, then forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ over $V$ collapses $\kappa$ to $\omega.$

Comment: This may help to make a natural formulation.

Comment: So what exactly is "uniform" here? Because that's a condition that somehow excludes adding many Cohen reals, as your answer here suggests.

Comment: It just means that the $\kappa$ I described above is the same for all $\mathbb{P}/p$,  for any $p \in \mathbb{P}$. Note that Cohen forcing adds a real, so this also applies to it, it just collapses $\omega$ to itself.