# fake and weak cardinals

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals, inner-models

Suppose $\lambda$ is a successor of a singular cardinal.  We will say $\lambda$ **fake** if there is a transitive set $M$ such that $\lambda \subseteq M$ satisfying $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$ (ZFC without powerset) in which there is a largest $M$-cardinal $\kappa < \lambda$ which is regular in $M$.  We will say $\lambda$ is **weak** if we can find such $M$ and $\kappa$ such that $M \models \kappa^{<\kappa} = \kappa$.

**Question:** If $\lambda$ is a fake successor of a singular, is it also weak?

Some motivation: To obtain some properties around singular cardinals of high consistency strength, one often creates weak successors of singulars using Prikry-type forcing. But to obtain other such properties, one needs to use successors of singulars that are not weak.  These two methods are in tension.  In practice, the examples of fake successors of singulars are also weak, since the witnesses may be taken from inner models satisfying GCH.  But I am wondering if there is a deeper explanation.

Remark: If $\kappa$ is supercompact and $\mathrm{cf}(\mu)<\kappa<\mu$, then $\mu^+$ is not weak.  Using Radin forcing, we can produce a model with many measurable cardinals in which every successor of a singular is weak.

Comment: Jesus, Agent Orange is really getting to you, isn't he? SAD.

Comment: I'll leave it to you to define sad cardinal.

Comment: A sad cardinal is one that won the popular vote, but not the college of cardinals?

Comment: Will you get an example of fake non-weak cardinal by taking a measurable cardinal $\kappa$, add a Prikry sequence and $\kappa^+$ many Cohen reals? Take $M$ to be a model of height $\lambda=\kappa^+$ with all the Cohen reals but without the Prikry sequence, ($M = H(\kappa^+)$ of the generic extension by the Cohen reals).

Comment: No, there is still $H(\kappa^+)^V$.

Comment: So $\lambda$ is weak if there is a transitive $M$ that witnesses its fakeness while having $\kappa^{<\kappa} = \kappa$? I see that I misunderstood the definition. I thought that you require that any transitive $M$ that witnesses the fakeness also witness the weakness.

Comment: Yes, now you have it right. Both are supposed to be $\Sigma_1$-ZF properties.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is fake, isn't some sufficiently nice core model will give you the witness for being weak too?

Comment: @Asaf, this sounds right, but I’m not sure if inner model theory is developed enough to make this claim in full generality. Maybe the question can be answered with some anti-LC assumption, or some crazy conjecture about ultimate L.

Comment: Assuming $\lambda$ is fake; why wouldn't the model $L_{\lambda^{+}}$ witness that $\lambda$ is both fake and weak? Being regular is a $\Pi_1$-statement and since $\lambda$ being "fake" is equivalent to $\mu = \cup \{ \kappa \in \lambda: \text{cf}(\kappa) = \kappa \} \in \lambda$ being regular; you've automatically got that $L_{\lambda^{+}}$ witnesses that $\lambda$ is fake. Isn't it the case that $L_{\lambda^{+}} \Vdash \mu^{<\mu} = \mu$?

Comment: $\lambda$ might not be a successor in L.

Comment: @Monroe Ohhh! I see it now, it might be the case that you've done something like, take a pair of measurable cardinals, force the larger to be the successor of the smaller, then force the smaller to have countable cofinality.. Cute. (I see my mistake now; interesting)

Comment: It also follows from the existence of $0^\sharp$ that every cardinal is inaccessible in L.

Comment: Do you know if successor of a singular cardinal of small cofinality above a supercompact cardinal can be fake?

Comment: @Yair I think the following might yield a fake cardinal above the supercompact; fix some measurable cardinal $\mu$ above the supercompact, and consider the model $M$ which is the direct limit of the first $\omega$ many iterates of the ultrapower generated by a normal measure on $\mu$; letting $\mu_\omega = \sup \{ j_k(\mu): k \in \omega\}\in M$, we have that $M$ thinks $\mu_\omega$ is regular, so unless I'm mistaken, $M$ should witness that $\mu_\omega^{+}$ is fake. (Fixed some typos)

Comment: @NotMike: note that $\mu_\omega$ is not a cardinal in $V$. Under GCH, it has size $\mu^+$. In fact, strengthening a bit the assumptions on $M$, I think that I can show that there are no fake cardinals above a supercompact cardinal: let's assume that M has a definable global well order. Then, in L(M), the axiom of choice holds and $L(M) \cap P(\kappa) = M \cap P(\kappa)$. In particular, $\lambda$ is successor of regular in $L(M)$ and we can apply Shelah's theorem and obtain that the approachability ideal $I(\lambda)$ contains $\lambda \setminus (S^\lambda_\kappa)^M$. Now, $\kappa$ is larger...

Comment: ... then the supercompact and thus $I(\lambda)$ is full except a single cofinality ($\mathrm{cf} \kappa$), which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

### This doesn't work. I'm leaving this as it might helpful to someone later on.

---

I think that the answer is yes, but my idea has a gap.

This happens for silly reasons: $V=L$ satisfies $\sf GCH$, and fake cardinals imply the existence of sharps.

Note that if $\lambda$ is a successor of singular cardinal which is not its successor in $L$, then $0^\#$ exists. In particular, if $\kappa$ is the predecessor of $\lambda$, then $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible in $L$.

So you'd like to look at $L_\lambda$, but remember, $0^\#$ exists. So that's actually a model of $\sf ZFC$, and in particular, has no last cardinal. But now force with $\operatorname{Col}(\kappa,<\lambda)^L$.
Now I ***think*** that th existence of $0^\#$ implies the we can find an $L$-generic filter, $G$, for this forcing, which in particular, does not add any bounded sets to $\kappa$. But now look at $L_\lambda[G]$ and it is a witness for the weakness of $\lambda$. Sad.

Comment: I will ask Sy about this.

Comment: He's definitely the man to ask about that.

Comment: He says $\kappa$-Cohen generics exist in $L[0^\sharp]$ iff $\kappa$ has countable cofinality in $L[0^\sharp]$.  So your argument doesn't work in general.

Comment: Well, but you should probably have access to much more complicated sharps, no?

Comment: Believe me, I have the best sharps.  But I don't know if we can derive anything but $0^\sharp$ from the existence of a fake successor of singular.

Comment: I misunderstood Sy.  Actually he can show that no matter what $V$ is, if $0^\sharp$ exists and $\kappa$ is regular in $L$ and of uncountable cofinality in $V$, then there cannot exist a $g \in V$ which is $\kappa$-Cohen generic over $L$.  So this means if we force with $\mathrm{Add}(\kappa)^L$ over $V$, then somehow this collapses $\kappa$.

Comment: Huh. Okay. I guess I'll leave this here, since this might help someone find a better idea.

Comment: [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184495/can-the-cohen-forcing-collapse-cardinals) is relevant to the remark Sy gave, in fact sharps are way too strong than what's necessary there.